# EFTracingProvider The 'data source' keyword is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to use `Entity Framework Tracing Provider` to trace EF query, I get `The 'data source' keyword is not supported`. error:

I have a DbContext in a project call `test.domain`:

```
public partial class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public EFDbContext()
            : base(EFTracingProviderUtils.CreateTracedEntityConnection("name=EFDbContext"), true)
        {
```

In my `test.web` project, my web.config connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Store;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I think it works with EF5 : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14492366/1394953